# Right-aligned image has 1px gap on Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013

Tags: html, image, email, outlook

In my email, there is a right-aligned image. And the problem is, its right side does not exactly stick to the right edge of parent table cell, in stead, there is a 1px gap. That only happens on Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013, not on other versions of Outlook and other email agents.

Please copy the code at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p9Lvun9p/) and send it to Outlook 2007, 2010, or 2013 to see the problem.

I had tried many solutions such as `border-collapes`, `mso-table-rspace`, `mso-line-height-rule`, etc, and still had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

When using images emails tend to perform more consistently when the width and height are also added to the  which surrounds the image, please see my edited version of your table holding your image.

```
<table align="center" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="ffffff">
<tr>
    <td width="600" align="right" bgcolor="ffffff" style="padding: 50px 0;">
        <table align="right" width="250" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="250" height="200" align="right">
                <img style="display: block;" src="http://placehold.it/250x200" width="250" height="200" border="0" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Problems can also arise when `<td>` or `<table>` have no fixed widths, but immediately outer `<td>` or `<table>` do, as the inner `<table>` or `<td>` may not inherit the widths properly.

I haven't had an opportunity to test this, but I will if I can.

Comment: I had a go at testing a few different things and it does seem weird! I even tried putting a 100% width spacer next to it to push it across, but the result was the same. Interestingly, when put into Dreamweaver the WYSIWYG window shows the dimensions of the table that the placeholder image is in as 250(251)? Sorry I couldn't be more help!